# Format a day from date as 15th instead of 15

Tags: formula, custom-field, date

I have a formula text field that convert the date from 15/06/2015 to 15 June,2015. Is there a way to get the postfix portion of the date ie : 15th.

My formula is :

```
TEXT(DAY( Wedding_Date__c ))+ " " +CASE(MONTH(Wedding_Date__c), 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
12, "December", 
"None") 
+ ", " + TEXT(YEAR(Wedding_Date__c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reference of others. YES you can get the postfix portion. Formula is :

```
IF( 
ISBLANK( Wedding_Date__c ), 
NULL, 
( 
TEXT(DAY(Wedding_Date__c))& 
CASE( 
DAY(Wedding_Date__c), 
1, 'st', 
2, 'nd', 
3, 'rd', 
21,'st', 
22,'nd', 
23,'rd', 
31,'st', 
'th' 

)&' '& 
CASE( 
MONTH( Wedding_Date__c), 
1, "January", 
2, "February", 
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June", 
7, "July", 
8, "August", 
9, "September", 
10, "October", 
11, "November", 
"December" 
)&','& 
TEXT(YEAR(Wedding_Date__c)) 
) 
)
```

Comment: Yes there is a way of course, what I meant is there is no formula to do it ;)
And I suggested another formula in order not to complexify the current one, and respect Salesforce best practice.

Comment: @Julien Hi thank you for your input. the formula above gives the desire solution

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.
You might want to use another formula :

```
CASE(MATH.Mode(DAY( Wedding_Date__c ), 10),
1, "st",
2, "nd",
3, "rd",
"th"
)
```

Comment: Suggest you also add 21, 22 and 23 to this; they are also normally exceptions to "th".

Comment: @Julien Gaïotto yes there is a way. Find formula below.

Comment: @KeithC yes thanks I completely forgot those ones :/